# Xamarin iOS - single view app memory leaks

Tags: memory-leaks, xamarin.ios

I created a single view application in Xamarin Studio, without making any changes to it, I deploy it onto an iPhone 5 running iOS 7.0.4.

Instruments then reported a dozen memory leaks after the app launched:
[image: Leak]

There are no interactions with the view whatsoever. The stack traces all look similar to this
[image: Stack Trace]

Please, can somebody tell me why this is?

Comment: I should add that my Xamarin Studio version is 4.2.2 (build 2), XCode version is 5.0.2, and Xamarin.iOS 7.0.4.209. All latest at the time of writing.

Comment: found some info here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5006915/938783 but the answer is almost 3 years old - not sure whether it's still relevant.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug we've already fixed internally, the fix will be included in Xamarin.iOS 7.0.7.

Comment: it looks like it really isn't fixed in 7.0.7. Retest shows me something similar. With a slightly different stack trace.

Comment: @AllenZeng: memory leaks are a disaster in Xamarin iOS. They occur everywhere mostly due to circular refs between native objs and managed objs. It really is a disaster for non-trivial apps. They leak everywhere. Xamarin seem oblivious. We are seriously rethinking Xamarin strategy as a result.

Comment: @HermanSchoenfeld seeing that there are leaks even in an unmodified app created from a template in Xamarin Studio I have to say that hardly surprises me... I must admit I haven't tested it with the latest version though. And yes, mission critical apps, oh heck, all serious apps should be really really careful with cross platform solutions.

Comment: @HermanSchoenfeld Can you tell me what version of Xamarin you are using?